# Which Schema.org type should be used for community / social groups?

Tags: schema.org

Using Schema.org. Couldn't find it (or was not sure):

**What should be the type for social / community groups? For example a Facebook group?**

```
bla bla .... itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/**what should be placed here** >
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might want to use [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization), which includes "club, etc.".

As of [version 2.2](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2), there doesn’t seem to be another related/appropriate type. If `Organization` isn’t appropriate for your case, you would have to fallback to [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) (or [`Intangible`](http://schema.org/Intangible), if you think of your community/group that way).